# DATEADD not returning correct dates for some rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql

**The function should return a new date after the current date and the num_of_flows is added. The num_of_flows is an integer value**

```
ALTER  function [dbo].[M20_22_GetLoanMaturityDate_FIN_10]
(
    @AcctAcid varchar(50),
    @ScheduleNum varchar(50),
    @bank_id varchar(6) = '03'
)
returns varchar(50)
as 
BEGIN
    Declare @lMaturityDate varchar(50)
    begin
            select @lMaturityDate = 
            case Finacle_Lrs.LR_FREQ_TYPE   
                             when 'W' then  dateadd(day, (Finacle_Lrs.NUM_OF_FLOWS - 1) * 7,Finacle_Lrs.FLOW_START_DATE)
                             when 'F' then  dateadd(day, (Finacle_Lrs.NUM_OF_FLOWS - 1) * 14,Finacle_Lrs.FLOW_START_DATE)
                             when 'M' then  (dateadd(month, Finacle_Lrs.NUM_OF_FLOWS - 1, Finacle_Lrs.FLOW_START_DATE))
                             when 'Q' then  (dateadd(month, (Finacle_Lrs.NUM_OF_FLOWS - 1) * 3, Finacle_Lrs.FLOW_START_DATE))
                             when 'H' then  dateadd(month, (Finacle_Lrs.NUM_OF_FLOWS - 1) * 6, Finacle_Lrs.FLOW_START_DATE)
                             when 'Y' then  dateadd(month, (Finacle_Lrs.NUM_OF_FLOWS - 1) * 12, Finacle_Lrs.FLOW_START_DATE)
                      end
            from    [TEST_EIMDW_Archive].[ARCHOWN].[FINCL10_LRS] Finacle_Lrs
            where   Finacle_Lrs.acid = @AcctAcid
            and Finacle_Lrs.shdl_num = @ScheduleNum
            and Finacle_Lrs.FLOW_ID in ('PRDEM','EIDEM')
            AND Finacle_Lrs.ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y' AND Finacle_Lrs.DELETE_FLAG= 'N'
            and Finacle_Lrs.bank_id = @bank_id
            and Finacle_Lrs.FLOW_START_DATE = ( select max(a.FLOW_START_DATE)
                            from   [TEST_EIMDW_Archive].[ARCHOWN].[FINCL10_LRS] a
                            where  a.ACID = Finacle_Lrs.ACID
                                and    a.SHDL_NUM = Finacle_Lrs.SHDL_NUM
                            and    a.FLOW_ID in ('PRDEM', 'EIDEM') AND a.ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y' AND a.DELETE_FLAG='N' and a.bank_id = @bank_id
        );
end
        return isnull(@lMaturityDate,null);

END
```

After doing some checks, I noted that 19629 rows are understated by altest one day when comparaing the orginal code on a oracle database. Please see oracle version of code:

```
FUNCTION GetLoanMaturityDate(AcctAcid VARCHAR2, ScheduleNum VARCHAR2) RETURN DATE IS
        lMaturityDate DATE;
    BEGIN
        begin
            select decode(lrs.LR_FREQ_TYPE, 'W', lrs.FLOW_START_DATE + (lrs.NUM_OF_FLOWS - 1) * 7,
                            'F', lrs.FLOW_START_DATE + (lrs.NUM_OF_FLOWS - 1) * 14,
                            'M', add_months(lrs.FLOW_START_DATE, lrs.NUM_OF_FLOWS - 1) ,
                            'Q', add_months(lrs.FLOW_START_DATE, (lrs.NUM_OF_FLOWS - 1) * 3),
                            'H', add_months(lrs.FLOW_START_DATE, (lrs.NUM_OF_FLOWS - 1) * 6),
                            'Y', add_months(lrs.FLOW_START_DATE, (lrs.NUM_OF_FLOWS - 1) * 12)
                     )
            into    lMaturityDate
            from    lrs
            where   lrs.acid = AcctAcid
            and lrs.shdl_num = ScheduleNum
            and lrs.FLOW_ID in ('PRDEM','EIDEM')
            and lrs.FLOW_START_DATE = ( select max(a.FLOW_START_DATE)
                            from   lrs a
                            where  a.ACID = lrs.ACID
                                and    a.SHDL_NUM = lrs.SHDL_NUM
                            and    a.FLOW_ID in ('PRDEM', 'EIDEM')
                               ) ;
        exception
            when no_data_found then
                lMaturityDate:=NULL;
        end;

        return lMaturityDate;
    END GetLoanMaturityDate;
```

Also here is the comparsion query I ran to see the incorrect rows:

```
SELECT eim.acid as eim_acid,it.[ACID] as it_acid,
eim.[MATURITY_DATE] as eim_maturity_date,it.[MATURITY_DATE] as it_maturity_date ,
eim.[DAYS_TO_MATURITY] as eim_DAYS_TO_MATURITY,it.[DAYS_TO_MATURITY] as it_DAYS_TO_MATURITY,(it.[DAYS_TO_MATURITY]-eim.[DAYS_TO_MATURITY]) as diff
FROM [TEST_EIMDW_BOJ_REPORTS].[BOJOWN].[loans_maturity_profile] eim 
inner join [dbo].[IT_LOANS_MATURITY_PROFILE] it on eim.acid= it.acid
where eim.MATURITY_DATE != it.MATURITY_DATE
```

Finally, below is the query result showing the comparison of the correct result set verus the one I currenty trying to fix on sql server:

[image]

Comment: Be careful here. You are calculating a date and then returning a varchar. You should return a date instead of a string. Also, scalar functions in sql server are notoriously poor performers. It might be a good idea to convert to an inline table valued function if this gets a lot of action.

Comment: @SeanLange noted, but, what I'm looking for is a way to reproduce the Oracle code in sql server. Any ideas?

Comment: I am not well versed in Oracle and would concede to Gordon's far better knowledge in that realm than I possess. See his answer below. Probably not what you want to hear.

Comment: Looks like he always need last day of the month. Using "End of month" (EOMONTH ( start_date [, month_to_add ] ) ) function would produce better results here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to add to what Gordon said, the exact behaviour of Oracle's `ADD_MONTHS` function is that if the source date is the last day of its month, then the return date is also the last day of the resulting month (regardless of the length of the month of the source date).

SQL Server has no similar function.

Which implementation is correct, or whether it matters, will depend on your particular circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle's `add_months()` and SQL Server's `dateaddd(month)` have different semantics, particularly at the end of the month.

So:

```
select add_months(date '2019-02-28', 1)
from dual

--> 2019-03-31
```

(see [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e68d1183b5baf58a95958ec4bfa5c5a6))

Whereas:

```
select dateadd(month, 1, '2019-02-28')

--> 2019-03-28
```

(see [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e68d1183b5baf58a95958ec4bfa5c5a6))

It can be a little tricky to emulate the Oracle behavior in SQL Server.  I'm not even sure if that is desirable.

Comment: Probably it should be "select add_months(date '2019-02-28', 1) from dual"

Comment: @Piotr . . . I swear, my code in questions seems to be worse when I actually test it.  In any case, the db<>fiddle was correct.

Comment: @GordonLinoff for what I'm trying to achieve it is desirable

Comment: Cannot construct data type date, some of the arguments have values which are not valid.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server "End of month" - EOMONTH (start_date[, month_to_add ]) function will behave similar to ORACLE add_months for the last day of the month.